# Error with YouTube.Thumbnails.set() (videoID not found)

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api

I'm trying to change the thumbnail of a YouTube video using Google Script.

Here's my code:

```
function setThumbnail() {
  YouTube.Thumbnails.set({
    videoId: "fvnpZIASTqI",
    media_body: DriveApp.getFilesByName('thumbnail.jpg').next()
  });
}
```

For reference, here's the YouTube video whose thumbnail I'm trying to change: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fvnpZIASTqI and I have verified my phone number (so, my YouTube channel has permission to set custom thumbnails).

But when I run this code, I get the following error message:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.thumbnails.set failed with error: The video that you are trying to insert a thumbnail image for cannot be found. Check the value of the request's `videoId` parameter to ensure that it is correct. (line 2, file "Code")

This seems like such a simple issue... but I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.

the set() function requires two arguments, not a single array.

The correct code is:

```
function setThumbnail() {
  YouTube.Thumbnails.set(
    videoId= "fvnpZIASTqI",
    media_body= DriveApp.getFilesByName('thumbnail.jpg').next().getThumbnail()
  );
}
```